# How to remove text between "()"

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Input:

**Dynamic Text (PDF 120 KB)**

Output:

**Dynamic Text**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str = "Dynamic Text (PDF 120 KB)";
document.write(str.replace(/\([^)]+\)/,""));  // Dynamic Text
```

- `\(` matches `(`. You need to escape `(` because it is a special character used to define a capturing group;
- `[^)]+` matches 1 one or more characters but `)`;
- Finally, `\)` matches the ending `)`.

#### References:

1. [JavaScript replace() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)
2. [JavaScript RegExp Object](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't feel like using a regex, you could do this:

```
var str = "Dynamic Text (PDF 120 KB)";

var result = str.slice( 0, str.indexOf('(') );
```

Takes a [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) of the string, starting with the first character, and stopping at the first instance of `(`.

*Note that this is the `String` slice, and not the `Array` slice, which doesn't have as wide browser support.*

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "Dynamic Text (PDF 120 KB)";
var new_text = text.replace(/\(.*\)/,"");
```

This should do it, but i would rather `use split()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var regExp = /\(.*\)/g;
alert("Dynamic Text (PDF 120 KB)".replace(regExp,""));
```